# JSON data working in one part of script, but not in another part

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following script which is not working for some reason:

```
success: function( widget_data ) 
{ 

    if( widget_data.d[0] ) {

        var j = 0;

        for ( j = 0; j <= widget_data.d.length - 1; j++ ) {

            $.getScript( "js/" + widget_data.d[j].script, function() {

                // this line is complaining about .widget_id
                alert(widget_data.d[j].widget_id);
            });

            // but this line works fine...
            alert(widget_data.d[j].widget_id);

        }

    }

}
```

I get an error on the following line, with one withing `.getScript`:

```
alert(widget_data.d[j].widget_id);
```

The error message is:

```
Cannot read property 'widget_id' of undefined
```

But the strange thing is, the following alerts work fine and return the correct values:

```
alert(widget_data.d[j].widget_id);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us html and is widget_header_ class?

Comment: Before I do that, I just tried the alerts within the `.getScript` and they stop working, they give the same error.  As soon as I move the alerts out of `.getScript`, the alerts start working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The getScript call runs asynchronously capturing the variable `j` not it's value at the time it is invoked. This means that `j` likely has the value that terminated the loop at the time the call returns.  You should call the `getScript` within a function so you can capture the value of `j` rather than it's reference.  Actually, it's probably better to actually capture the "widget" object itself, as you can see in the code sample.

```
success: function( widget_data ) 
{ 

    if( widget_data.d[0] ) {

        var j = 0;

        for ( j = 0; j <= widget_data.d.length - 1; j++ ) {

            getWidgetScript( widget_data.d[j] );

            alert(widget_data.d[j].script);

            // but this line works fine...
            alert(widget_data.d[j].widget_id);
            alert(widget_data.d[j].title);

        }

    }

}

function getWidgetScript(widget) {
    $.getScript( "js/" + widget.script, function() {
        $( ".widget_header_" + widget.widget_id ).text( widget.title );
    });
}
```

Comment: Will this ensure that the script(s) load before the widget_id is used?

Comment: @oshirowanen What will happen is that the widget object will be different for each function invocation. The `widget_id` will be that associated with the widget supplied as the parameter.  Previously, it was attempting to use the value that `j` had when the asynchronous call returned not what it had when getScript was invoked.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work